# Mail is not being delivered

Tags: vb.net, email

I am sending mail using `SmtpClient`. while attempting to send any-mail, I am getting success response. But mail is not getting delivered.

```vb
Dim mMailMessage As New Net.Mail.MailMessage

Dim client As System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient = New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("domain", 587)
client.EnableSsl = True
client.Timeout = 100000
client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
client.UseDefaultCredentials = False
client.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username***", "password")

Dim msg As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
mMailMessage.[To].Add(pstrToMailid)
mMailMessage.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("frommailid")
mMailMessage.Subject = pstrSubject
mMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True
mMailMessage.Body = text

If Not pstrfilenames Is Nothing Then
    Dim lint As Integer
    Dim larrattachment() As String
    larrattachment = Split(pstrfilenames, ",")
    For lint = 0 To larrattachment.Length - 2
        attachment = New Net.Mail.Attachment(larrattachment(lint))
        mMailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment)
    Next
End If
client.Send(mMailMessage)
```

Comment: Can you tag the language used?

Comment: Its a VB.NET @tadman

Comment: *"I am getting success response"*. Then your code is successful so there is no issue to be addressed here. What happens from the SMTP server onwards is out of scope. You would need to look at the SMTP server and the recipient's server to see what they may be doing with the mail. Maybe it's in a junk folder or maybe it is being quarantined. That's nothing to do with your code, so you need to find out where the actual issue is first.

Comment: Agree with jmc; your mail is probably in the junk. Go to https://www.mail-tester.com/ and get the email address from there (every page visit is unique) then send it a mail with your program, wait some time and then go collect your results from the website. It will tell you how spam-looking your email is, and also give you some way of testing that your mails are actually leaving the sending server you have chosen

Comment: You might even find depending on the receiver environment, then depending on the nature of attachments that the email aren't even getting to the junk mail.  Many mail washers will simply ditch emails based on attachment size or type.  if you do this without attachments, does it get through?